# How can I capture time lag of an event passed through various components in a distributed system?

Tags: java, distributed-system

I have a group of components connected and placed in a distributed system. AN events gets injected into the starting components and gets passed through all components which are placed in different region containers and under different time zone. I want to capture time lag of 
this event from the time of it being passed entering into the  first component to going out from the last component and being notified to the subscribed client. Note, There should not be any negative time difference coming while measuring the lag when event flows from one component to other wherein bot two components are in different time zones.This is a strictly distributed system here.

Comment: Why not use UTC in first place?

Answer (score 0):

Simply by getting the time difference to a fixed point.

Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() returns the ms to the 1.1.1970 UTC.
If you save the millseconds right before you begin your execution chain and compare (subtract the start time from the end time) that value is the elapsed time in ms.

Comment: What is the fixed point here? Can this fixed point hold true for all the components running in different region and timezones in a distributed set up?

Comment: How do you compare two times? You have to convert them to the same "version".  
 Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() returns the time passed since the 1.1.1970 - no matter which time zone you are in. Even if I have a completely different time zone than you do the time difference will be equal if we call the method in the exact same moment. - They are comparable and time zone independent.

Comment: Can this provide linear ordering of events with external consistency? I am thinking of using Google Spanner TrueTime. Can that be useful in this scenario?